# SQLite Foreign Key is null AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I tried already all what i found here in Stackoverflow but nothing helped me thats is why im asking once more. I try to make a database with sqlite in android but when i opened my database to see what my programm saved i have by this foreign key always the value null.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_PERSON +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, IDENTIFICATION INTEGER)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_LOCATION +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LOCATION TEXT, EMPLOYEE INTEGER , FOREIGN KEY(EMPLOYEE) REFERENCES person_table(IDENTIFICATION))");
}
```

[Screen of sqldatabse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b8XC.png)

Can someone help me?
Code of methods:

> ```
> public boolean addDataToLocation(String Location){
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
>     ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
>     contentValues.put(COLL_2, Location);
>
>     long result = db.insert(TABLE_LOCATION, null, contentValues);
>     if(result == -1)
>         return false;
>     else
>         return true;
> ```

Comment: The [foreign key column may be NULL](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html). Please show how you insert data into TABLE_LOCATION

Comment: Well, SQLite just does what it's told to do. You have to provide the value of the foreign key column and pass it with the *contentValues* just like you do for the location. The database can't possibly know to which person a location belongs

Comment: How can i provide the value of the foreign key?

Comment: You determine the id of the person to which the location belongs. I don't know how much you know about relational databases but the idea is that later on one can find out who is where by doing a [SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) with something like an  INNER JOIN ON persons.ID = locations.EMPLOYEE

Comment: Something like that?
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select IDENTIFICATION from "+TABLE_PERSON+ "inner join "+TABLE_PERSON+" on "+ COLP_3+" = "+ COLL_3, null);

Comment: But don't mix this up: first you have to *insert data correctly*. Later on you can retrieve groups of data from multiple tables by using JOIN. So for example if you have a person named "Homer" with ID = 13 in table persons and he is "on the sofa" then you should save 13 as value for EMPLOYEE (this is the foreign key) and "on the sofa" as value for LOCATION in table locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have two issues/misunderstandings.

The first is that specifying a foreign key doesn't automatically select a suitable value and update the column with such a value. Rather defining a foreign adds a constraint that says that the value must be a value that exists in the respective column of the parent table. If it does not then a conflict will occur.

As such you have to determine a suitable value (in your case an existing **IDENTIFICATION** value).

The second is that the SQLite provided with Android, by default does not have foreign key support turned on. Foreign key support can be turned on by either using

- the **[foriegn_keys pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys)** to turn support on
- or by using the **SQliteDatabase** method **[setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean))**

noting that foreign key support cannot be turned on within a transaction. As such it is advisable to turn foreign key support on as soon as possible.

- If using as sub class of SQLiteOpenHelper then it is suggested to override the **onConfigure** method and use the **setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled** method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so for the first after i tried a little i understand that and for the second it was just implemented. The solution that i needed was that it must be provided a value to Employee and this value need to be Identification. I solved this with return in the first add-method.
But thanks for your answer, appreciate it